# Blank screen displayed on option menu click

Tags: android

I have option menu on my activity. I am displaying another activity on click of options menu using below method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.some_menu:
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(MyActivity.this,SomeActivity.class));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.someother_menu:
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(MyActivity.this, SomeOtherActivity.class));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

First menu, `some_menu`, is working fine. It displays mentioned Activity. However, when I click second menu, `someother_menu`, it displays blank black screen. No idea what is happening.

XML for SomeOtherActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/follow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp" 
    />

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/follow_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the code of your `SomeOtherActivity`. I guess you have forgotten to call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`.

Comment: I have setContentView in my "SomeOtherActivity" protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.follow); }

Comment: And you are sure that the layout does display something? Please add the xml to your question, not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: post the error message you get from Logcat window, when you start the second activity... also make sure it is defined in your androidmanifest.xml file..

Comment: @WarrenFaith: It does not display anything. Just a blank blank screen.

Comment: @Rahulgarg No error message in LogCat. Infact, LogCat displays Displayed activity xxx.xxx.xxx.MyActivity

Comment: @Rahulgarg Also, activity is defined in Manifest file

Comment: I mean does the layout has something in it that can be displayed? Please add your layout xml to the question!

Comment: the given layout is by default **blank**... unless you are adding some data to it in SomeOtherActivity.java code..   Post your expected result from that activity and mainly the someotheractivity.java code...

Comment: Yes. Layout is blank. I was expecting the list to be displayed. But for some reason list is not getting populated. That's why blank screen is displayed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is empty, so you will not see anything -> blank black screen.

Add the text attribute to your TextView to show some dummy text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"   
     android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/follow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp" 
    android:text="DUMMYTEXT"
    />

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/follow_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to check why my list didn't get populated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution, but try:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.some_menu:
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(MyActivity.this,SomeActivity.class));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.someother_menu:
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(MyActivity.this, SomeOtherActivity.class));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: No it's not. I have put the return outside the switch.

Comment: I'm sorry, but then I'm out of ideas. I'm not in front of my own computer, so I can't test.